# How can I create a network that takes a single digit as an input and outputs a 2D array?

Tags: tensorflow, python

I want to create a network that can take a single digit (float) and then output a 2D array. I'm using TensorFlow in Python and so far I have this for my model and training.

```
i = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(i)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(K, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(i, x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
r = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

x_train is a 1D np.array of numbers and y_train is an array of 2D np.array. There are as many entries in x_train as there are 2D arrays in y_train.

At the moment I get the error shown below.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [3,2] and labels shape [1920000]
     [[node loss/dense_30_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at C:\Users\PATH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_7241]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

So far I have tried changing the loss function to 'categorical_crossentropy' but this caused another error due to the fact it is expecting binary data.

Does anyone know either what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve that I am trying to do?

Comment: First, the output of a Dense layer is 1D, not 2D (if you don't take account of the batch_size dimension). Also, why do you use a softmax activation ? This is suited for classification, and discrete densities of probabilities... Is it your case ? Finally, what are the shapes of x_train, y_train, and how much is K ?

Comment: Thanks. x_train shape (3,) is and y_train shape is (3, 800, 800, 1). K is 2. It is not the case that I need classification, I've just replaced it with 'relu'.

Comment: Ok, so actually the output of your network has shape (2,) (so 1 dimension, 2 features), which does not match the shape of one label that is (800, 800, 1). So you need to change the architecture of your net in order to have a output with shape (800, 800, 1) (which by the way is 3D, not 2D).

Comment: I see, what kind of layer can I use to increase the dimensions from 1 to 3? I was thinking of Conv2D or Conv3D but I'm reading that these do not change the number of dimensions.

Comment: That really depends on your aplication. The stupid but basic aproach is to use a Reshape layer at the end I'd say. And, one more question, do you have only 3 samples in your dataset ?

Comment: Hi. Programming issues are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: some more info about the application would be useful - but usually DNNs have a fixed output size for a give fixed input size. you could use zero-padding on your inputs/outputs to make them all a certain fixed size? But please give us context!